# Ruby Integer(), Array(), et al -- what are they? Where do they come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've come across conversions of the form Array(value), String(value), and Integer(value) on occasion.  It appears to me that these are just syntactic sugar for a call to the corresponding value.to_a, value.to_s, or value.to_i methods.

So I'm wondering:

- Where/how are these are defined?  I can't find them in Object, Module, Class, etc
- Are there any common scenarios for which it's preferable to use these rather than the corresponding/underlying to_X method?
- Could these be used in type-generic coercion?  That is, can I do something along the lines of

  ```
  [Integer, String, Array].each {|klass| klass.do_generic_coercion(foo) }
  ```

?  (...and no, I don't really want to do that; I know the type I want out, but I'm looking to avoid the case statement.)

Comment: I don't do much ruby, but I suspect it's the syntax for casting.

Comment: There's no such thing as "casting" in Ruby. In fact, the whole *idea* of casting only makes sense in a weakly typed language like C, but Ruby is strongly typed. These are just methods like any other method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a good and difficult question. Let's answer the three parts.

**First part**

To find the definition, it is important to realize that the name of the method is "Array", etc., which can be quite counterintuitive, since methods are usually lowercase...

```
irb> method(:Array)
=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#Array>
```

This tells you these are defined in Kernel, and thus available everywhere without requiring an explicit prefix.

**Second part**

`Array()`, `String()`,... are conversion methods. Calling `obj.to_a` will return an array, but will raise an `NoMethodError` if obj doesn't `respond_to? :to_a`. So the typical case when you'd prefer using `Array()`, `String()`, instead of `to_a` or `to_s` is when you are not positive an object responds to a given conversion method.

`String(obj)` will return `nil` if obj doesn't `respond_to? :to_s`. String(obj) will also check that the result of to_s is actually a string; it should be, but maybe an overly creative programmer decided to return something else?

Most other conversion methods act the same way, but `Array(obj)` is different. It will return `[obj]` if obj doesn't `respond_to? :to_a`. It will actually call `to_ary` (which is the implicit conversion operation, while `to_a` is the explicit one).

There is another important way to convert objects in 1.9 (and upcoming 1.8.8): `Array.try_convert(obj)`. This returns `nil` if the obj does not `respond_to? :to_ary`. It will not call the `to_a`. Although they are longer to type, you might prefer using them when writing very general code that might accept different types of objects and want to avoid converting a hash to an array by mistake, for example (since `Hash` has a `to_a` method but not `to_ary`). When your method requires an array-like object and you are willing to do an explicit conversion, then `obj.to_a` is fine. The typical use of `Array(obj)` would be in a method that accepts either a single `obj` to act on, or a list of objects (although typically this is written as `[*obj]`).

**Last part**

Hopefully, the answers to the first two parts give you your final answer...

You can use:

```
[Integer, String, Array].each {|klass| klass.try_convert(foo) }
```

or

```
[:Integer, :String, :Array].each{|method| send(method, obj)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Between this and DigitalRoss's answer, I learned what I needed and much more.

Answer (score 8):

Good question! Let's see if we can figure it out.

```
Ross-Harveys-MacBook-Pro:ruby-1.9.1-p376 ross$ irb
irb(main):001:0> Object.ancestors
=> [Object, Kernel]
irb(main):002:0> Kernel.ancestors
=> [Kernel]
irb(main):003:0> Kernel.class
=> Module
irb(main):004:0> Kernel.public_methods.include? "Array"
=> true
```

So, it looks like these are methods in the Kernel module that are mixed in to Object, so they are available without specifying a receiver. We might also want to peek at the C implementation, in object.c:

```
VALUE
rb_Array(VALUE val)
{
    VALUE tmp = rb_check_array_type(val);

    if (NIL_P(tmp)) {
        tmp = rb_check_convert_type(val, T_ARRAY, "Array", "to_a");
        if (NIL_P(tmp)) {
            return rb_ary_new3(1, val);
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

One thing seems easy to conclude, the default `.to_a` is deprecated, so it does seem like `Array(x)` is the canonical way to do the conversion. It apparently does nothing if given an Array, calls `.to_a` if that's present, and if not it just wraps its argument in an Array.

Regarding whether `to_a` is deprecated...well, I said "the default":

```
Ross-Harveys-MacBook-Pro:puppet_sd ross$ irb
irb(main):001:0> class X; X; end.new.to_a
(irb):1: warning: default `to_a' will be obsolete
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for showing how you found it out. This will be very helpful in future projects!

Comment: Your answer is close, but I find it both incorrect (.to_a is not deprecated!) and incomplete. Check my response below.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't realize you were talking about the default Object#to_a, which is rightfully gone in 1.9. So your answer is close(r) and still incomplete ;-) Array(x) will call to_ary if one is defined. I think the notion of implicit conversion (to_ary) and explicit conversion (to_a) is both subtle and important.

Comment: Wow -- what a terrifically informative answer.  Thanks so much!  (Marc-Andre answered the third part as well, which is why I "accepted" his; the two together make a very interesting and instructive read.)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

They are Defined in Ruby Kernel Module, like:

```
Array(), Complex(), Float(), Integer(), Rational(), Stirng(), etc.
```

I found those method references in Dave Thomas's Pickaxe book ["Progamming Ruby 1.9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356085)", page 555.

For example: Array(arg) will convert arg as an Array, following are copied from the book:
"Returns arg as an Array. First tries to call rg.to_ary, then arg.to_a. If both fail, creates a single element array containing arg( or an empty array if arg is nil)."
   ex.

```
 Array(1..5)   # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the simple version is like this:

- `object.to_a` tries to convert 'object' to an Array using a class member function.
- `Array(object)` tries to make a new Array using 'object'.

I can re-define what `.to_a` means for a given class (it is just another member after all).  The `Array(...)` call is defined in Kernel so it behaves the same for any class.  I typically use type conversions of the style `Array(...)` when I don't know ahead of time what type of object will be passed in.  It's better at handling cases where an object doesn't know how to convert itself to an array or can't be converted to an array.  If the object to be converted is the result of a long or complex expression, using the `Array(...)` style is often clearer.  I save the `.to_a` form for instances when I know the class of the object and exactly what to expect from the output of `.to_a` (mostly instances when I have written or modified the `.to_a` member function myself).