# Dynamically create a Numeric given a class

Tags: ruby

Given a string `'123'`, I can create a `Float` or `Integer`:

```
x = Float('123.45')
y = Integer('123')
```

As an exercise in dynamic typing, I want to extend `Numeric`, the top-level number class, with a method that converts the number to a string, reverses it, and then back to its original type.

This would allow me to do this:

```
x = (123).reverse
// x == 321
```

or this:

```
y = (54.321).reverse
// y == 123.45
```

One implementation looks like this: (this works correctly)

```
class Numeric
  def reverse
    str = self.to_s.reverse

    if self.is_a?(Float)
      return Float(str) # or str.to_f
    elsif self.is_a?(Integer)
      return Integer(str) # or str.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

But I want to create the result dynamically rather than checking a list of types. I tried using `Class.new()`:

```
class Numeric
  def reverse
    str = self.to_s.reverse
    self.class.new(str)
  end
end
```

I thought this would work since I can call `Float('123.45')` or `Integer('123')`. However, I get these errors:

```
irb(main):047:0> (54.321).reverse
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Float:Class
    from (irb):44:in `reverse'
    from (irb):47
    from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):048:0> (123).reverse
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for Fixnum:Class
    from (irb):44:in `reverse'
    from (irb):48
    from /Users/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

So I have two questions:

- How does `Float('123.45')` or `Integer('123')` work if they don't implement `new`?
- How can I implement `Numeric.reverse()` without any conditionals?

I know there are other cases where this won't work (like negative numbers), but I'm not concerned with those issues (yet).

Comment: It also doesn't work for `Float::INFINITY`. Also a good answer to the first question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039343/ruby-integer-array-et-al-what-are-they-where-do-they-come-from/).

Comment: And since they are just methods, you can dynamically call them with [`Object#send`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-send). But then it still won't work for integers since they're not actually instances of `Integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *How does `Float('123.45')` or `Integer('123')` work if they don't implement new?*

   They call the `Kernel` methods `Kernel::Float` and `Kernel::Integer` respectively, more info [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html)
2. *How can I implement `Numeric.reverse()` without any conditionals?*

   Like this:

   ```
   class Numeric
     def reverse
       str = self.to_s.reverse
       method(self.class.to_s).call(str)
     end
   end
   ```

   The `method` method converts string or symbol to a method, which then can be called using `call` and passing the string you want to it.

   Example: `method((123.2).class.to_s).call('321') # => 321.0`

Comment: What if the number has leading zeros...say '0112'

Comment: While casting it on `Float` or `Integer` all leading zeros will be omitted as expected

Comment: `(0112).reverse
NameError: undefined method 'Fixnum' for class 'Fixnum'`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna that's just because `112.class == Fixnum`

Comment: Thats true, `Kernel` doesn't have a `Fixnum` method, just an `Integer`. Not sure yet how to get around that..

Comment: @gunn I do know that I was just clarifying that this code doesn't work in all cases. And this string reverse thing doesn't work with numbers having leading zeros. In case of Fixnum it should be self.superclass.to_s to make it work.

Comment: Even though you go for self.superclass.to_s the leading zero problem exists.

Comment: `class.superclass` works for `Fixnum` but stops working for e.g. `Float`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna there is no "leading zero problem" - `Integer(0112.to_s.reverse)` runs without errors. That it's octal and `0112 == 74` might be what's surprising you

Comment: Yeah I know that its octal but OP wants that to be represented as 2110 right...I was talking about that...Its not just the negative numbers he is going to ignore